# path issues with FFMPEG Bash script to concat and encode across multiple subfolders

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal, echo, subdirectory

I'm trying to write a bash script for Mac OSx Terminal to compress a series of GoPro .MP4 videos from the SDcard directly into a smaller .MP4s on a local network server. The GoPro saves .MP4s in the 100GOPRO folder on the card. After filming, I will through that folder and manually put .MP4s from each game into subfolders within the 100GOPRO folder, named A1, A2, A3, etc.

Folder structure

```
/GoPro/DCIM/100GOPRO/
               -------/A1/
                       -----GX01xxx1.mp4
                       -----GX01xxx2.mp4
               -------/A2/
                       -----GX01xxx3.mp4
                       -----GX01xxx4.mp4
                       -----GX01xxx5.mp4
                       -----GX01xxx6.mp4
```

...etc

I would like then like to run a script from the 100GOPRO folder that will do these steps:

1. Within each subfolder, auto-create a file.txt with the names of the subfolder's .MP4s in the format to concat the files (each line has "file 'GX01xxx3.mp4'")
2. Pass that subfolder's file.txt as the input to ffmpeg to reencode and save to a network folder with the name A1.mp4 or A2.mp4
3. Repeat for each subfolder and quit.

I'm getting hung up on the dynamic path to the subfolder's file.txt. My code just creates a file.txt in the 100GOPRO folder, and appends all the subfolder contents into that single long combined text file. The output then would create a correct first MP4, but second MP4 contains folder 1 and 2, then 3 contains 1, 2, and 3, etc.

Here's the script I ran:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in A*/*.mp4 ; do
echo file \'$f\' >> list.txt ;
done && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt /Volume/Server/Videos/A$f.mp4 && rm list.txt
```

Clearly, failing in how that path for echo to save in the subfolder A*, how to call that subfolder's file.txt as the input for ffmpeg, and how to name the output after the folder.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to get the directories, and then make the list of files for that directory.  You could use `find` if you want more control, or a shell glob for simplicity (but this could accidentally match against other files).

```bash
for d in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'A*'); do
    printf "file '%s'\n" $(cd $d && echo *.mp4) > $d/inputs.txt
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $d/inputs.txt /Volume/Server/Videos/${d:2}.mp4
done
```

or the following loop using a shell glob:

```bash
for d in A*; do
    # same code as above
done
```

---

##### Explanation

- The find looks for directories matching `A*`, and limited to subdirectories only 1-level deep; note, specifying a directory(the `.`) is necessary on MacOS when using the default find command (BSD flavour), but with the GNU flavour (installed with brew or on Linux) the default directory is the current directory (`.`)
- Since `ffmpeg` expects the file paths to be relative to the list, we `cd` into the directory in a subshell, and generate the list of files with the glob `*.mp4`, and the `printf` formats that into a file list but iterating over it
- the `ffmpeg` command is as you specified, the output filename uses the directory name, except it trims the first two characters (transforming `./A1` -> `A1`)

Comment: So close now!  
I got "find: illegal option -- m" so I added a period after find. Worked.
The printf then creates an inputs.txt file in each folder, but the text has the path included when it should just have the file name with no path.  

So I get this error.  
**"Impossible to open './A4/./A4/GX01xxx1.mp4'  
./A1/inputs.txt: No such file or directory"**
If I manually create the input.txt file without the path included, the ffmpeg line works great.
How do I change your printf to get this inputs.txt with **"file 'GX01xxx1.mp4'**" without the path to the file?
Thank you!

Comment: @NoobCoder What you tried interactively, and the error doesn't match.  For example, in your error the path is not what my suggestion would generate. I would expect to see `'./A4/GX01xxx1.mp4'`, but you have `A4` repeated twice. Also, based on the error it seems you are on MacOS.  Maybe it's related to that, by default CLI tools on Macs are pretty old, it's difficult to know what's supported.  I updated the answer to not use find, and to print a path relative to the inputs.txt

Comment: @suvayo: Yes, I'm on Terminal on MacOS. Your first version  `for` loop using `find` works, while the new one doesn't. (The ouput files are all named ".MP4"). However,  updating the `printf` that you provided combined with the earlier version `for` loop does it perfectly. Thank you! Hours of my life saved. I put the two solutions that you helped me with into an answer below, because the comment space was too small to include it.

Comment: @NoobCoder well, if my solution partially helped you, at least upvote it.  And like I said, it's very hit and miss with MacOS. Look into installing a more recent bash, and gnu tools using macports/brew.  Also, in the future, when asking a question, please mention details like your platform, shell, shell version, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work two ways with @suvayo's code! Thank you.

When I couldn't figure out how to get `printf` to create a file list without the path included, I was able to get it to work by nesting another loop within the directory loop using `echo`. I trimmed the extra 5 characters "./A2/" from the inputs.txt path with {f:5}:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'A*'); do
    for f in $d/*.mp4 ; do
        echo file \'${f:5}\' >> ./$d/inputs.txt
        done
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $d/inputs.txt /Volumes/Server/Videos/${d:2}.mp4
done
```

However, the more elegant way is using a combo of the 2 versions of @suvayo 's answer. (the output file name wasn't right when I just used `for d in A*; do`)

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'A*'); do
    printf "file '%s'\n" $(cd $d && echo *.mp4) > $d/inputs.txt
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $d/inputs.txt /Volumes/Server/Videos/${d:2}.mp4
done
```

This is great. In the end, each folder contains the original .MP4s that were combined, along with the inputs.txt that was used to concat those files together. Wish I weren't such a noob, so I could upvote the answers more.

Comment: Did you see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Save the file list to a bash array, then loop over that. Tune the `ffmpeg` invocation to your liking.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a files=( $(find A* -type f -name \*.mp4) )

for file in "${files[*]}"; do
    fbase=${file%.mp4}
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "$file" "/Volume/Server/Videos/A${fbase}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP asked.  `$file` is not a list of files to be concatenated.  Your output file name is also wrong (same mistake as the OP's code example)